# Step by step tutorial in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write my helloworld code using javascript and html.
So,  I thought of picking up a project and iterating from there.

Lets say, I have a path to xml file.
1) Display the contents of the xml file as it is (i.e treat it as a text file irrespective of the markup)

Thats it.. actually.. there is no step 2 :) 
But, I have very limited background in html as well.
can someone help me what will be the helloworld.html (or helloworld.js) be so that I can run it on the browser??

I would really really appreciate it

Many thanks

Comment: So you want us to do your work for you?

Comment: Wow wow wow. What are you trying to do there? Displaying an XML file in JavaScript is really no simple chore. This isn't a beginner level thing, certainly not a "Hello World" type script.

Comment: @zerkms: nope. I just want to get started.

Comment: Congratulations, I've never seen down votes accumulate so fast!

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: oh.. can i read a text file instead.. i want to basically display something by reading a file

Comment: @SteveWellens: Thats ok.. I am not very clingy on my stackoverflow points

Comment: @Fraz: so start from learning js basics?

Comment: how can you write a tutorial for somehting you don't understand yourself?

Comment: @charlietfl: Well.. I amnot writing a tutorial. ? I am asking for a tutorial..

Comment: The reason this is tough for you is that you need to write something to deal directly with `XMLHttpRequest`, something even many experienced Javscript programmers are loath to do without the benefit of an AJAX library. You don't specify JQuery or anything like that in your tags. "Open a file" might be pretty basic in *other* languages/environments, but for Javascript in a browser it's anything but.

Comment: The main purpose of js in the browser is to manipulate an html document. So why don't you start with basic html? My suggestion, write one one, then try to use js to interact with it somehow, then come back here with a more focused question.

Comment: a google search for `xml ajax` will return lots of results

Comment: Reading a file may be difficult from javascript because it is meant to be used for client side web applications.  It would be a security risk to allow random file-reading on everyone's computers.  As such, you should probably do something else for your first javascript programming.

Perhaps reading and altering an html table would be better?

Anyway, w3schools is a good place to start learning [html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer your question with a somewhat usable answer, and what I think most developers probably would do in the real world, is to use a library like [JQuery](http://jquery.com).

In this case, the code is straightforward:

Your HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Your Javascript:

```
$(function() { $('#result').load('test.xml'); } );
```

You need to make sure that your test xml file is served on the same domain as your javascript file.

Comment: Thanks.. 
Just wondering.. why no one else could have just helped me with these two lines rather than taking an offense of it. But thanks :)

Comment: @Fraz Well, there is a contingent on here that downvotes/trolls any hint of JQuery in answers to a question that doesn't specifically mention it. So the way you tagged your question implies you want to do this with raw out-of-the-box javascript, where this is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For an introduction to Javascript you can do a lot worse than http://eloquentjavascript.net